# Mathematica can't simplify ellipse-related trig equation over reals?

Tags: trigonometry

```
f[t_] = -4 + Sqrt[(-Sqrt[3] + 2*Cos[t])^2 + Sin[t]^2] + Sqrt[(Sqrt[3] 
+ 2*Cos[t])^2 + Sin[t]^2]
```

The function above is identically 0 for all real values of t. However:

```
FullSimplify[f[t],Reals]
```

just spits back the original function.

I also tried TrigReduce, TrigExpand, etc, to no avail.

How do I make Mathematica simplify things like this?

For those interested: I'm playing w/ ellipses, and f[t] represents the 
sum of the distance from the focii minus the actual value of the sum 
of the distance from the focii. The more general case:

```
x[t_] = a*Cos[t]  
y[t_] = b*Sin[t]  
focus[a_,b_] = Sqrt[a^2-b^2]  
f[t_]=Sqrt[(x[t]-focus[a,b])^2 + y[t]^2] + Sqrt[(x[t]+focus[a,b])^2 + y[t]^2]
```

where f[t] is constant for real t when a >= b (probably when a < b 
too, but things get a bit complex in that case)

Answer (score 1):

Simplification uses heuristics, so there's no guarantee it'll find the simplest form.  As you'll see below, it takes some work to make the simplification possible.

Note: In your example you were using incorrect syntax: the second argument of `FullSimplify` can't be `Reals`.  It must be a set of assumptions about some variables.  Take a look at the examples on the doc page to see how to use assumptions: [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullSimplify.html).

After correcting this mistake, Mathematica still needs some guidance to be able to handle this.  Your expression has the sum of two square roots:

```
expr = -4 + Sqrt[(-Sqrt[3] + 2*Cos[t])^2 + Sin[t]^2] + 
  Sqrt[(Sqrt[3] + 2*Cos[t])^2 + Sin[t]^2]
```

Let's transform it so it'll only have one square root and see if that helps:

```
Simplify[Expand[(expr + 4)^2], t \[Element] Reals]

(* ==> 16 *)
```

Since `(expr + 4)^2` is 16 for all real `t`, `expr` is either `0` or `-8`.  By substituting in `t -> 0` and noting that the function is continuous, we can quickly verify that `expr == 0` for all real `t`.